# Get single elements from an array?

Tags: c

I am trying to print each `char` in `s` array one at a time. The program I have printed all the letters after the defined index in the array.

The problem I am facing is after that the user inserts the phrase then it is allocated. How do you call letters from the string using pointers?

Can you use `strtok` to split this string, I tried setting the `delim` to "" got no output.
In other word make it a list like a Python `split()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
        
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
   
    //printf("%s \n", s);
        
    for (int i = 0 ; i <strlen(s); i++){
        printf("%s \n", &s[i]);        
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `%s` to print a single character?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("%c\n", s[i]);`?

Comment: what should I use, `%ch`?

Comment: You should use `%c`

Comment: And use `s[i]`, not `&s[i]`

Comment: @JonathanLeffer can you please explain you for loop in detail, please

Comment: @m3sfit You should read the documentation for functions you're using.

Comment: See also [How to prevent buffer overflow in `scanf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168).  Also read POSIX [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
and note the `m` modifier ('optional assignment-allocation character').  If it is available on your system (it isn't on macOS X, for example), then you could use that instead of the `malloc()` and `realloc()`.  You should also read the POSIX specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).

Comment: The loop I wrote steps through each element of the string, up to but not including the null terminator byte (avoiding the overhead of calling `strlen()` on each iteration, which an optimizer might or might not avoid), and uses the conversion specification to print a single character (plus a newline) and passes a single character, `s[i]`.  The characters are already available individually by using array indexing on the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%c\n", s[i]);
```

or

```
printf("%c\n", *(s + i));
```

Comment: can you explain the second `printf` statement why did you write `*(s+i)`

Comment: Because `s[i] = *(s+i)`

Comment: They are equivalent. S has the address of the first element of the array, you sum i positions to that and then access the value that was stored in that position.

Answer (score 1):

```
len = strlen(s);

for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++){
    printf("%c\n", s[i]);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() 
{
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c \n", s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```